# water heater - flow problem

Tags: water-heater, pipe, water-pressure, hot-water

got a new [3 liter instant water heater](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B009P2LG0C/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) installed. When the heater is off, water flow is normal. When it is on, about one liter or so hot water flows and then there is no water.

What might be the reason here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like there is a flaw in the heater or its piping, and there's no way for us to debug it from here without a LOT more information.

Comment: Hi @DanielGriscom, the issue was that the plumber connected to the wrong pipes. Fixed it by swapping the inlet and outlet and it is now working fine. Thanks. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to take the time to a) expand the question with some info, and b) post the answer. That way, in the future someone with your same problem would be helped by your knowledge. Your call!

Comment: @rahulroy9202  you should answer your own question to preserve the information for others who may encounter this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The plumber installed the heater with the inlet and outlet pipes switched. Swapping the inlet and outlet fixed the problem.